# Change multiple mail folders' permission at once in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an email account with hundreds of folders, each has multiple subfolders. I need to change the user permission of all those folders/subfolders at once. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Exchange on an in house server or a server that you have access to you could take a look at [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tips_from_the_inside/archive/2011/11/03/set-outlook-folder-permissions-using-powershell.aspx). It should be helpful in what you want to do.

If you are using Exchange on a hosted platform then you would need to check with your provider to see if they can give you access to their power shell.

FROM ARTICLE:

Use Add-MailboxFolderPermission to run against a root folder and all of its subfolders with the following steps:

1. Get a list of folders from the mailbox
2. Add the permission to the folder

We first need the list of folders to which we will apply permissions. Use Get-MailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet for this. We want the FolderPath value that is returned in the format “/Folderpath”.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics owner | Where { $_.FolderPath.Contains("FolderName") -eq $true }
```

Then use the Add-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet to assign the permissions. The format for the folder name is “Mailbox:FolderPath” so we need to adjust the result from the earlier command.  The following is an example in which Jane’s manager, John, wants her to access his Clients folder and all subfolders:

```
ForEach($f in (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics John | Where { $_.FolderPath.Contains("/Clients") -eq $True } ) ) {
     $fname = "John:" + $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\");
     Add-MailboxFolderPermission $fname -User Jane -AccessRights Reviewer }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where I had a folder with about 100 subfolders I needed to reassign permissions to. I found the easiest way  was to create a new folder with the permissions I wanted (for instance if you want your assistant to be able to file emails for you), then copy the previously existing folder with 100 subfolders into that folder.  The old folder and all the subfolders inherit the rights you assigned the new folder.
(You can use the same process to move the folder with 100 subfolders back under the folder it originally started from if you want to, but you may have to wait a little while for all the readdressing to take place if you have a lot of emails.  If the files do not show up soon, close and restart outlook.)

Comment: That does not work in Outlook 2013.